# При обновление сбрасывается вкладка таба, как это можно исправить?

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня на сайте вкладки. Как можно исправить скрипт открытия их, чтобы оставалась ссылка, по которой можно перейти и откроется нужный таб(вкладка)

```
<!-- Базовый контейнер вкладок(табов) -->
<div class="tabs-box">
 <!-- Список вкладок -->
 <ul class="tabs">
 <li class="active" rel="tab1">Вкладка 1</li>
 <li rel="tab2">Вкладка 2</li>
 <li rel="tab3">Вкладка 3</li>
 <li rel="tab4" class="tab_last">Вкладка 4</li>
 </ul>
 <!-- Контейнер для блоков с содержанием -->
 <div class="tab_container">
 <div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
 Содержимое Вкладки 1
 </div>
 <!-- конец #tab1 -->
 <div id="tab2" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
 Содержимое Вкладки 2
 </div>
 <!-- конец #tab2 -->
 <div id="tab3" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
 Содержимое Вкладки 3
 </div>
 <!-- конец #tab3 -->
  </div>
 <!-- конец .tab_container -->
</div>
<!-- конец .tabs-box --> 


Тут скрипт для открытия 

<script>
    // вкладки с содержанием
    // http://dbmast.ru
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    /* в режиме вкладок */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_accordion").removeClass("d_active");
        $(".tab_accordion[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");
    });
    });
    /* дополнительный класс tab_last, 
    чтобы добавить границу к правой 
    стороне последней вкладки. */
    $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
</script>
```

Comment: сохраняйте activetab в localstorage при переключении вкладки, а при открытии страницы проверяйте

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я уже находил информацию что нужно использовать localstorage, но опыта у меня к сожалению нету, а работу сдавать завтра. Я не смогу сделать то что вы посоветовали, ибо js я не учил. Можете пожалуйста помочь с этим?

Comment: "чтобы оставалась ссылка, по которой можно перейти и открылся таб" (с) — Имеется в виду создание прямой ссылки, которая при загрузке сразу будет открывать нужный таб?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Да, это имелось в виду. Или что-то похожие, чтобы можно было зацепится за таб и открыть его. Можете помочь с этим пожалуйста?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/ - - можно получить кусок URL `var id = window.location.search;` — через `replace()` вырезать оттуда ненужное и получить "чистое" название id... которое можно будет использовать так: `document.getElementById( id ).click();` — кликнув на нужную кнопку (в ссылке должно указывается именно его id, это автоматический клик на указанный id)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Спасибо за оперативный ответ, но все что вы написали я ни разу не использовал и как их связать, я не смогу. Поискав в интернете, ничего не понял к сожалению. Если это вас не затруднит, то сможете ли вы накинуть код, как он должен быть? А то я в js не смыслю и воспользовался табами ибо понравилось. Все остальное сделал для работы. Осталось по сути это доделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что сработает, но можно пробовать (на тестовом сайте сработало), здесь в песочнице не сработает.

```js
(function(){
/*Переключение вкладок*/
$('.link').on('click', function(){
  $('.link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active'); 
  $('.tab').hide(); 
  $('.tab').eq( $(this).index('.link') ).show();
});/*конец*/

/*При клике на любую кнопку, в URL должно появится записанное в href...
При загрузке получаем эту запись и достаем оттуда число*/
var x = +(String(window.location.hash).match(/#tab(\d+)/)||[0,0])[1];
/* Если число не найдено - будет получен ноль из второго массива */
/* Подробнее → Google: Массивы, оператор 'или', match(), регулярные выражения 
  по полученному числу 'x' - кликаем на нужный класс, который откроет вкладку */
document.getElementsByClassName('link')[x].click();

})();
```

```css
.tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #123;
  padding: 3px 8px;
}

.tabs a.active {background-color: #045acf;}

.tab {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 10px; margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.tab.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <a class="link active" href="#tab0">Вкладка 1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#tab1">Вкладка 2</a>
  <a class="link" href="#tab2">Вкладка 3</a>
  <a class="link tab_last" href="#tab3">Вкладка 4</a>
</div>

<!-- href == ссылается на id, но их не существует, это добавлено лишь для
изменения URL. А само переключение вкладок основано на классах 
внимание, что счет для JS начинается с нуля -->

<div class="tab show">1111</div>
<div class="tab">2222</div>
<div class="tab">3333</div>
<div class="tab">4444</div>
```

А код самих табов... подробнее описан тут - - [JavaScript переключаемые вкладки - табы (и немного CSS)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-css/982073#982073) , чтобы переключать их по классу, и не запариваться с id и их номерами.

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает. Удачи вам в жизни!!!